# Looking for meanings of the word "Right"

Tags: meaning

The word "[right](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/right)" has a variety of meanings, including "to correct" but this use would apply after something goes wrong. Can the word be used as "to prepare" -- that is, to set something up in a particular way? Can it ever be used to mean "to intend" (again, related to before the fact) or something like "to set a direction"?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary?

Comment: Besides the one I linked to? I don't have my OED handy.

Comment: If you have checked the dictionary, then I don't understand why you are asking the question. Did you read all the definitions? Do they not cover what you are asking? Do you have reason to expect "right" to mean something not covered there? Is there a reason you can't just use a different word that means what you need it to mean?

Comment: I expect that connotations and non-standard uses might be known to people even if they haven't been codified in dictionaries. I'm hopeful that someone has heard a use of the word (either archaic or more modern) which connects to either of these sense.

Comment: The might, but it would be helpful if your question contained more of a context and not just asking if a couple of random definitions can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Your first definition of *right* finds its common usage in the example "to right a wrong". As such from my understanding, the usage of the word "right" always stands to contrast a "wrong" direction or state. For example, to "right a ship" means to reverse a capsized vessel.

As such, I don't believe your latter two usages ("to prepare", or "to intend") can stand on their own without a contrast.

Answer (score 0):

You can "set the right []" or "prepare the right []" [course, direction, program, etc...] before the fact but to "right [something]" in the usage you have suggested first it must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar though not identical uses in the OED.

For my request of "to set a direction"
"Of a way or course: Direct, going straight towards its destination", "To guide, direct", "Directed straight forward" and "Leading in the proper direction or towards the place one wishes to reach" all, before an event

For my request of " to set something up in a particular way"
"To set up, establish, to raise" and "to assume an upright position" again, before anything goes wrong.

Source is pages 669 to 674 in the 2 volume OED.

Comment: Doesn't it show they're obsolete? The online OED — Third Edition, 2010 says that they are. (Isn't the two-volume work the *Shorter Oxford English Dictionary*?)

Comment: Some are obsolete, yes but I didn't discount that in my Question (in the comment I mentioned "archaic" which, not identical to obsolete, leads in that direction, though my language of "can it be used" does -- my bad). The 2 volume is not the shorter, I don't think. I'll crack out the magnifying class and check if you would like.